# How to compensate top talent within Dev Team

Tags: scrum

Members of a development team will have different qualifications, skills, and experience levels.

How would an organization that has implemented Scrum place a higher value on one individual over another in a Dev Team? From my experience, Dev Teams performance are measured usually as a team metric as titles and roles are not recognized within Scrum.

Comment: Is there practical real-world problem you are trying to solve? Otherwise maybe pm.stackexchange.com would be more useful

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn’t. I’m a junior on a team with a guy who has more than a decade of Java experience at companies people may know. That information doesn’t even seem to factor into how my team assigns work.

Comment: To clarify my comment, I mean that Scrum wouldn’t prescribe a way to do this. Performance evals are however you see fit.

Comment: You should be trying to eradicate this - whatever knowledge the most valuable team members have should be used to teach the least valuable members. There should be an end goal of having all the team members able to do all tasks - or least have 2+ bus ratio for all tasks/technologies

Comment: What is the practical application you're considering? What is your employer's current framework for compensation? What is your position in the organization and what change are you trying to achieve? Are you designing a new compensation process from scratch or trying to argue against whatever rules are currently in place? Theoretical questions are often hard to answer concretely. Real world scenarios are easier to fit into the Stack Exchange Q&A format.

Answer (score 9):

Titles and roles are not recognized *by the Scrum Framework*. That does not mean you cannot have them *in the company*.

Your team can consist of a junior widget maker, a senior widget maker, a widget tester and a intern and they can all have different job titles and pay scales. They can get raises and promotions differently.

The only difference with Scrum is that their title and pay is not important in the Scrum Process. There, they are all just a "development team member". No one can command somebody else because of their title. A seniors complexity estimation does not overrule a juniors complexity estimation. An intern has the same voice in retrospective meetings as anybody else.

A line manager not directly involved with the team (since line manager is not a role in Scrum) should probably listen to the full Scrum team to find out who pulls their weight and who doesn't, but other than that it's not different from before. Find out who does a good job, reward them with money and titles.

Comment: "Find out who does a good job, reward them with money and titles. " - What metrics could be used as it is usually the Team itself that is being measured? And how would knowing that individual performance will be rewarded (conversely punished) affect the Scrum Team, specifically transparency.

Comment: @paulj, "punish" is a strong word. Please do not punish your developers if they're doing their best.